# Is it possible to change css property with setTimeout in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, settimeout

I would like to change some css properties during 2 second delay made with setTimeout in jquery ?

Here's my example code

```html
   $(document).ready(function() {
 
    setTimeout(function(){
       
         $('.loader,.background').fadeOut(200);
$('.loader,.background').css({overflow:'hidden',width:'100%',height:'100%;'}});
 });
       
 }, 2000);
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is this code not working? What exactly happens when you run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple situations, you can use also the `delay()` method of jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.loader,.background').delay(2000).fadeOut(200);
  $('.loader,.background').delay(2000).css({
      overflow: 'hidden',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%;'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just move your `2000` after the second-to-last closing curly brace rather than the last one (which corresponds to your call to `document.ready`).

I don't have your HTML on hand, but this JS should suffice:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  setTimeout(function () {

      $('.loader,.background').fadeOut(200);
      $('.loader,.background').css({
          overflow: 'hidden',
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%;'
      });

  }, 2000);

});
```